# yii2 tutorial "Working with Forms" -- add field

Tags: php, forms, yii2

I am new to Yii2 and tried to work out the tutorials first.

I simply tried to add a new field (name: group) to the "Working with Forms" Guide referring to this webpage: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-start-forms.html#.

But user input from the added field doesn´t appear in the model.

The model:

```
class EntryForm extends Model
{
    public $name;
    public $email;
    public $group;  // additional attribute !!!!!!!!!!!

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['name', 'email'], 'required'],
            ['email', 'email'],
        ];      
    }   
}
```

The Site Controller stays without any changes to the guide.

Entry-Form:

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'name')->label('Your Name') ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'email')->label('Your E-Mail address') ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'group')->label('Your Group name') ?>      <!-- additional input !!!!!!!!!!! ->

    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton('Submit', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
    </div>
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

Entry Confirm:

```
...
<ul>
    <li><label>Name</label>: <?= Html::encode($model->name) ?></li>
    <li><label>Email</label>: <?= Html::encode($model->email) ?></li>
    <li><label>Group</label>: <?= Html::encode($model->group) ?></li>       <!--additional attribute !!!!!!!!!!! ->
</ul>
...
```

Notes:

Except the additional field "group", everything works fine.

User input in the "group" field appears in $_POST as expected.

But it does not appears in the model if I call $model->getAttributes()

I already checked the documentation of model->load() but couldn`t find any hint.

Thanks a lot for any help.

Comment: beacuse `group` is not a safe attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A model's validation rules serve two purposes:

- Ensure that fields entered in a form are entered properly
- Define which `form fields are allowed to be assigned to a $model`
  variable

you are missing the second point here so change your model rules function to

```
 public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['name', 'email'], 'required'],
            ['email', 'email'],
            ['group', 'safe'],
        ];      
    }
```

and it will work

Comment: Thanks a lot. I really didn't get the point that you need a validation rule even if there is no special need to enshure a form check for missing input.

Comment: read this http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/161/understanding-safe-validation-rules/ it will be helpful in understanding